# Generar números capicua en un arreglo

Tags: java

Soy nuevo en esto y tengo una duda, tengo que hacer un programa que cree un arreglo de tamaño aleatorio entre 10 y 20 elementos, cada elemento tiene que tener de 1 a 5 dígitos y cada elemento de este arreglo tiene que ser *capicua*, o sea que se lea igual al derecho que al revés.

Lo que pasa es que hice este programa que genera números aleatorios y luego mediante una conversión de entero a *string* valida si es *capicua* o no, y que al validar que sea *capicua* lo ingresará al arreglo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    int n = (int)(Math.random()*20) + 10;
    int[] numeros = new int[n];
    
    for(int x = 0; x < numeros.length; x++){

        int number = (int)(Math.random()*99999);
        String numCapicua = Integer.toString(number);
        StringBuilder cap = new StringBuilder();
        cap.append(numCapicua);
        cap.reverse();
        String newCapicua = cap.toString();
        int newCap = Integer.parseInt(newCapicua);
        if(newCap == number){
            
            numeros[x] = newCap;
            
        }
            
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++){
        
        System.out.print("" + numeros[i] + "  ");
        
    }        
}
```

El problema es que los números que no son *capicua* los imprime como ceros en el arreglo y lo que quiero es que cuando lea un número y vea que no es *capicua* lo ignore y vuelva a validar el siguiente número aleatorio generado.

Por ejemplo: si el programa genera los números 10, 202, 455, 4567,101, 333, 123, 8 y 41 en la salida debería salir: 202, 101, 333, 8, pero lo que me sale a mi es 0, 202, 0, 0, 101, 333, 8, 0.

No se si estoy haciendo algo mal o haya otra manera mas eficiente de hacerlo.

Trate con un do *while* y me pasaba lo mismo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que cuando usas el `for` siempre sumará un +1 a `x` (aunque no sea capicua) lo que ocasiona que en esa posición asigne un "0" porque nunca restringes o validas el ingreso de ese dato, entonces en este caso te ayudará más usar un `while` ya que solo debes sumar +1 cuando ingrese el `if` que tienes.

Ejemplo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = (int)(Math.random()*20) + 10;
    int[] numeros = new int[n];

    int x = 0;
    while (x < numeros.length) {
        int number = (int)(Math.random()*99999);
        String numCapicua = Integer.toString(number);
        StringBuilder cap = new StringBuilder();
        cap.append(numCapicua);
        cap.reverse();
        String newCapicua = cap.toString();
        int newCap = Integer.parseInt(newCapicua);
        if(newCap == number){
            numeros[x] = newCap;
            x++; // Solo suma +1 cuando ingresa al if
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("" + numeros[i] + "  ");
    }
}
```

Si no me expliqué bien no dudes en consultarme en los comentarios.

Espero te sirva. Saludos ;)

Comment: Graciass!!!:) Me funciono muy bien! Trataba de hacer algo similar con el while que pusiste pero al final nunca me funcionaba. Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes poner un if al momento de imprimir los números, si es diferente a 0, imprime los números:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++){
      if(numeros[i]!=0){
        System.out.print("" + numeros[i] + "  ");
      }  
    }
```